# Why is my shape not rotating along its apparent bounding box?

Tags: svg, rotation, bounding-box

I'm trying to rotate this image (`#small`) so that it's upside down, but the shape isn't rotating as I'd expect.  It seems to me that the bounding box would be much smaller than its apparent axis of rotation.

What's actually going on here and how can I fix it?

#### MWE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="test-image"
     viewBox="0 0 816 1110"
     width="816" height="1110"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <g id="base">
      <svg viewBox="-8 -10 16 20" >
        <path d="M 7.989,3.103 C 7.747,-0.954 0.242,-8.59 0,-10.5 c -0.242,1.909 -7.747,9.545 -7.989,13.603 -0.169,2.868 1.695,4.057 3.39,4.057 1.8351685,-0.021581 3.3508701,-2.8006944 3.873,-3.341 0.242,0.716 -1.603,6.682 -2.179,6.682 l 5.811,0 C 2.33,10.501 0.485,4.535 0.727,3.819 1.1841472,4.3152961 2.5241276,7.0768295 4.601,7.16 6.295,7.159 8.158,5.971 7.989,3.103 z"
              style="fill:#000000" />
      </svg>
    </g>
    <g id="small">
      <use xlink:href="#base" transform="scale(0.1,0.1)" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <!-- debugging grid -->
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="black" fill="white"/>
  <rect width="80%" height="80%"  stroke="lightgrey" fill="white" x="10%" y="10%" />
  <rect width="60%" height="60%"  stroke="lightgrey" fill="white" x="20%" y="20%" />
  <rect width="40%" height="40%"  stroke="lightgrey" fill="white" x="30%" y="30%" />
  <rect width="20%" height="20%"  stroke="lightgrey" fill="white" x="40%" y="40%" />
  <line x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="50%" y2="50%" stroke="lightgrey" />
  <line y1="0%" y2="100%" x1="50%" x2="50%" stroke="lightgrey" />

  <!-- rotation test -->
  <use xlink:href="#small" x="50%" y="50%" />
  <use xlink:href="#small" x="50%" y="50%" transform="rotate(10)" />
  <use xlink:href="#small" x="50%" y="50%" transform="rotate(20)" />
  <use xlink:href="#small" x="50%" y="50%" transform="rotate(30)" />
</svg>
```

[image: output]

Comment: transform="rotate... can take up to 3 parameters, the last 2 are the rotate origin and if omitted (as you've done), they default to 0, 0 which is the origin (the top left of the local co-ordinate system)

Comment: @RobertLongson I suppose that makes sense, but I guess I was expecting it to be 0,0 with respect to the bounding box of the shape I'm transforming. I guess on a related note, do you know how I could align the centers of the shape and the overall SVG document?

Comment: Use transform="translate(x, y)" where x and y are numbers and then draw the shapes centered on the local origin.